# jQuery slice() Not Working Despite Chrome Dev Tools Console Verification

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is an extremely odd and simple issue that I've been stuck on now for FAR longer than I care to admit! My slice() function isn't working, anymore. I've checked the syntax a billion times. It seems to have been working at one point, that's the most complicated fact.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   jQuery("h2.page_title").css('background','lime');
   jQuery("h2.page_title").text().slice(2);
});
```

[image]

The file and function are running fine, hence the lime background. However, slice() will not work, or even update through my console. It doesn't matter which element I target in the DOM. I've cleared caches, restarted all WAMP services, etc. I know the real solution is something extremely more stupid, so if you have any tips on what could be causing this, it would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: You aren't using jQuery slice() because `text()` returns string. You are using native `String#slice()`. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: charlietfl, When it was working, I was using .slice() right on the element without .text()... however it doesn't work either way.

@AnkitAgarwal, the expected output in this example is what's shown in the console.

Comment: Still doesn't explain what you are wanting to accomplish

Comment: I was trying to slice a word as shown in the console. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `slice` the original string isn't changed. It only returns you the sliced string. You should do the assigning yourself -

```
var str = jQuery("h2.page_title").text().slice(2);
jQuery("h2.page_title").text(str);
```

or in one row -

`jQuery("h2.page_title").text(jQuery("h2.page_title").text().slice(2));`

Comment: `.slice()` returns "jQuery" so `str` here is a jQuery object, not a text object.  Please add clarification that this is a string slice not a jQuery slice

Comment: Thank you so much. I knew it was something stupid I was missing. I wasn't aware slice didn't change the string... just a variable.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss He is using the slice method on a string. Hence he is not using the jQuery slice method.

Comment: @nicolascolman - yes, perhaps my hasty comment did not phrase it well but I agree that it is NOT jQuery `slice()` at play here.

Answer (score 1):

In my humble opinion the jQuery `slice()` is actually a misleading name that leads to confusion as it is not really the same as native JavaScript slice (for strings as you use it here).  jQuery slice returns a jQuery object, NOT a string.

jQuery `.slice()` falls into the "Traversing and Filtering" category.

> "Reduce the set of matched elements to a subset specified by a range
>   of indices."

jQuery slice: https://api.jquery.com/slice/

Native string JavaScript `.slice()` on the other hand returns a string

> "...extracts a section of a string and returns it as a new string,
>   without modifying the original string."

### SO, to address your specifics,

```
jQuery("h2.page_title").text().slice(2);
```

**Returns a string starting at index 2 of the text - and you do nothing with that string.**

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Completely agreed and I see where my confusion was now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to slice the first 2 characters can use [`text(function)`](https://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function) to return the  resultant. This will also loop over any of that selector and do instance specific slicing for  all

```js
jQuery("h2.page_title")
   .css('background','lime')
   .text(function(_, currTxt) {
      return currTxt.slice(2);
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="page_title">First heading</h2>
<h2 class="page_title">Second heading</h2>
```